# What's the deal with the "Quantum Gravity Research Organization"?

Tags: soft-question, quantum-gravity, education

[www.quantumgravityresearch.org](http://www.quantumgravityresearch.org)

It looks like they're an independent research group, but the main guy behind it, Klee Irwin, sounds crackpotty:

> Klee guides the team in developing emergence theory, a new, first principles quantum gravity theory that unifies space, time, energy, matter, information and consciousness.

But the rest of the people associated it seem like they produce actual papers, but I'm not really capable of judging how legit they are.  Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about the trustworthiness of a specific organization, and not physics.

Comment: I had a look,. It seems that there was an entry for Klee Irwin in wikipedia that was removed. here is a not so good entry http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Klee_Irwin#cite_note-13 . See the last paragraph and the last footnote

Comment: Ask this on the chat, or find another site where physics isn't defined on...

Comment: It's a fake, but as things go, it's a better funded and more subtle fake than usual.